# How to count the lines with the specific value at Cognos 11?

Tags: syntax, count, cognos, boolean-expression, cognos-11

lets say i have a column with many lines but only two values, A and B:

i am trying unsuccessfully to count only lines with A - in a summary calculation for a dashboard (without making a new column for this specific calculation)
the expression which gives me syntax error is this:

count([column] = 'A')

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use an if then else construct:

count( if([Column]='A') then ([Column]) else (Null))

Comment: great! worked perfectly, couldn't find it anywhere, do you know where can i find resources for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF-THEN-ELSE or CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE to create your own count:

```
sum(
  if ([Query Item] = 'A')
  then (1)
  else (0)
)
```

or

```
sum(
  case
    when [Query Item] = 'A'
      then 1
    else 0
  end
)
```